# Which preposition is correct to use in "to conjugate __ 3rd Person Singular"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Is it *at/on/in* with the following phrase:

> to conjugate .... 3rd Person Singular

So far I consistently use "at". Am I right?

**Edit:**
*"have" is conjugated ... the 3rd Person Singular, becoming "has".*

Comment: What's the full context? Have you tried looking for similar examples online?

Comment: Can we have a *complete example sentence*, please? So far as I know, ***to conjugate*** can only be used transitively of an actual verb (OED *To inflect (a verb) in its various forms of voice, mood, tense, number, and person*). So I don't think there should be *any* contexts where *"to conjugate XXX 3rd Person Singular"* would be valid with XXX = [some preposition]. Google NGrams finds nothing for ***conjugate XXX third*** with XXX as a "wildcard" (nor with *...first* or *...second*). But I'm okay with *I can conjugate **"to be" into** second person singular **giving "are".***

Comment: None of those are used. The 3rd person of [verb] in [tense] is [y]. That said, we would use "to conjugate a verb in the present tense", but not with the persons (I, you, he, she, etc.). The verb conjugate is used with tenses, not with the person. For the person, you state it as I did in my first sentence.

Comment: @Lambie — *Conjugate* is used with voice, mood, tense, number, and person.

Comment: @TinfoilHat We do not say **to conjugate at, on or in the third person*.

Comment: @Lambie — We can *conjugate for the third person singular*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I wouldn't say that. You conjugate a verb, you don't conjugate for a person. Third or otherwise.  When you conjugate some verb, the **third person is** this or that.

Comment: @Lambie — https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Grammatical-Person.htm

Comment: @TinfoilHat To conjugate for third person as given in The Free Dictionary just sounds like the person who wrote it is clueless.

Answer (score 1):

The prepositions **in** and **for** are the most commonly used when speaking of conjugation of verbs.

For example:

> "Arabic verbs conjugate for number and gender..."
> -- *Colloquial Arabic (Levantine)*, Leslie J. McLoughlin (Routledge, 1982)

or

> The present-tense form of the verb **take**   in the third person  singular is **takes**.

or

> In English we conjugate for present tense third person singular by adding an **-s** to the end of the base form of the verb: *live**s***, *sing**s***, *smile**s***, *fight**s***, *sleep**s***.

Of course, it is also possible to speak of conjugations without using a preposition:

> **sleep**'s past-tense is **slept**. I slept. You slept. He, she, or it slept. We slept. You slept. They slept.

Comment: So which Pronoun to use with: " Verb is conjugated ... the 3rd Person Singular.

Comment: @YerOrda Your example sentence doesn't have enough context to decide which. Give a real sentence.